# Breaking changes Prime NG 11 Migration

Tags: primeng

I'm correcting some imports to prepare to migration and im facing this issue when correcting virtualScroller import:

[image]

How can i solve?

I saw that

> clearCache()

has been removed too

how i replace this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is not available so there is no replacement, you simple need to remove it.

Comment: thank you, i appreciate